# .a file in Pods become red when I turn to debug mode

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

In release mode app run fine.But in debug mode,build faild and .a file in Pods become red:
[image]

And it's said library not found:

[image]

This is my build setting:

[image]

debug and release's other linker flags is the same.

This problem waste my all day.Hope someone can help me.

Comment: Try compiling pods as project first

Comment: Have you checked the linker search paths?

Comment: You have twice the -ObjC flag in debug, did you try to remove it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Build Active Architecture Only: YES
```

this solve my problem.